# Some Page links are not working when i am not logged in Pyrocms

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, content-management-system, pyrocms

I have a strange issue when i am logged in and exploring the pages created from CP all goes well. But when i am logged out and go to the same page it says Page missing. What is the problem? Also this is only happening only on those pages where i am not using any tags to display data from database tables. It is happening on about use page etc

Comment: Did you change any of the Access options under the Options tab for each of the pages?

Comment: yes i tried changing to live from draft.its working now thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. Using Access options i change from default to live and now it is working fine.